# Is the probability of getting the mail today vs tomorrow independent from the day?

Tags: probability, independence

I need some help seeing if I understand independence and conditional probability.

Let's say I'm expecting a package. It's priority mail so I know at most it will take $3$ days to come. The probability of getting it in the first day $\Pr(A)$ is $0.\overline{33}$. The probability of getting it the second day given it didn't arrive the day before $\Pr(B \mid \neg A)$ is $0.50$ (right?). And the probability of getting it in the $3$rd day given not day $1$ or day $2$ $\Pr(C \mid \neg A \wedge \neg B)$ is $1$ (right?).

So if my logic is correct so far, if I investigate independence, I will find: $\Pr(B \mid \neg A)$ is $0.5$ and $\Pr(B)$ is $0.\overline{33}$; therefore, the events are not independent. Same applies for the third day.

In English, not getting a package in a particular day influences the probability of getting it in the other two days by improving the odds, which intuitively makes sense. Or am I off the mark?

Comment: I needed to see the math

Comment: You have some additional unstated assumption, presumably something like: "The package is equally likely to arrive on any one of the three days." Otherwise, it's easy to make prior probabilities that invalidate your statements. For example, let's say there is a 1/3 chance of the package arriving and a 2/3 chance of it arriving the third day. Then the probability it arrives on the second day is 0 even given that it didn't arrive on the first.

Comment: @DerekElkins thanks! That didn't cross my mind, but yes, I'm assuming it's equally likely for the mail to arrive in any of the three days.

Answer (score 4):

Showing that $P(B)\neq P(B\mid\lnot A)$ proves dependence of $B$ and $\lnot A$, and you have done this nicely. However, to me it's not the most intuitive way to go about it.

If you get a package on one day, then you will definitely not get it on any other day. That sounds very dependent.

More rigorously, another way to define independence of $A$ and $B$ is that $A$ and $B$ are independent iff
$$
P(A\text{ and }B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)
$$
Is this equality fulfilled?